# FaceBook UI using new PHP/JS API instead of FBML

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, iframe, fbml

Where do I find information on styling my application to facebook look/feel in a PHP/JS (JavaScript) canvas app in an iframe?

I have some code that is a FBML canvas app, but facebook is phasing that out and it seems you can only use the new PHP API with an iframe and the javascript (XFBML) SDK.

I have most of it working, but I can not figure out some simple things - like in FBML to show a nice facebook styled message, I could just do:

```
<fb:success><fb:message><?php echo $fbmessage; ?></fb:message></fb:success>
```

or

```
<fb:error message="An error has occurred." />
```

Those FBML tags seem to no longer parse - probably not supported by XFBML.  So what are the replacements, or even better, where is the documentation on how to use the new iframe/javascript canvas setup and style it easily?  Maybe a CSS file?   JS calls?   XFBML plugins?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no real guidelines for iFrame applications. Maybe it's worth consulting with a front end designer/developer to devise a visual framework for your application.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up styling everything myself, I was just hoping to save some time and utilize something FB may have provided.    Luckily some of the libraries out there such as JQuery make it a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things that you'll need to check to make sure your app will work as an iframe app instead of an FBML one:

- Make sure your app's page are complete and valid XHTML
- Make sure you have the `xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"` declaration on your root  element
- Wrap any existing FBML content in the following markup:

`<fb:serverFbml>`
      `<script type="text/fbml">`
        `<!-- your original FBML markup here... -->`
      `</script>`
    `</fb:serverFbml>`

- Lastly, if you aren't already, make sure your page calls `FB.XFBML.parse()` after calling `FB.init()`.

Hopefully this gets you up and running.